# How do I resolve 'CAS is unavailable' error?

Tags: tomcat

I am managing a web based application hosted on RHEL Machine, the is Active Directory Services hosted on Window Server 2016,  authentication trust is established with LDAP/App integration.
All has been working fine except of recent that the system keeps on flagging *CAS is unavailable* whenever attempt is made to login into the application.

I imported a newly generated certificate into the Linux server using keytool, things starts working, but it stopped never to work again.
I have tried all within my limited knowledge about all this stuff are bind together.

Here is part of the log

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Mar 21, 2019 3:31:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/cas/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/cas.war
Mar 21, 2019 3:31:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 21, 2019 3:31:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 21, 2019 3:31:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9776 ms

Mar 21, 2019 6:13:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
Mar 21, 2019 6:13:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 21, 2019 6:13:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 21, 2019 6:13:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Mar 21, 2019 6:13:01 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/cas] appears to have started a thread named [oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Mar 21, 2019 6:13:01 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/cas] appears to have started a thread named [perf4j-async-stats-appender-sink-CoalescingStatistics] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Mar 21, 2019 6:13:01 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/cas] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
:
```

Comment: I suppose the problem is related to the cas web application; have you made contact with the developers of this application regarding the errors? Tomcat appears to be giving some useful information about it during the shutdown.

Comment: This may become more pertinent for Stack Overflow, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26180770/4957508

Comment: Thanks for your response. please, assuming the developer could not be reached to help out, what is s suggested alternative solution or a work-around? A detailed and definite guide will be highly appreciated, please.

Comment: Kindly help me with a step by step approach to address the above issue, I have tried to reach the developer but no way, what is the the way out? Like a suggested alternative solution/work-around?